# Making a decomposition chart in R

Tags: r

I am attempting to make a decomposition chart in R.  My data only goes to 2023, but for some reason the axis on the seasonal chart section go up to 2030.

I used the following code:

```r
bovine <- ts(March_15_Charts_for_R_, frequency = 4, start = c(2016,1))
plot(bovine)

dec <- decompose(bovine, type = ("additive"))
plot(dec)
```

```r
 dput(March_15_Charts_for_R_) structure(list(Quarters = c("2016q1", 
  "2016q2", "2016q3", "2016q4", "2017q1", "2017q2", "2017q3", "2017q4", 
  "2018q1", "2018q2", "2018q3", "2018q4", "2019q1", "2019q2", "2019q3", 
  "2019q4", "2020q1", "2020q2", "2020q3", "2020q4", "2021q1", "2021q2", 
  "2021q3", "2021q4", "2022q1", "2022q2", "2022q3", "2022q4"), 
  Number of Cases = c(1, 11, 1, 5, 1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 1, 7, 0, 11, 4, 2, 1, 10, 
                      2, 2, 3, 9, 2, 3, 9, 15, 6, 7, 5)), 
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -28L))
```